# Ca't Make a .NET Core POST Request to work

Tags: .net

I am trying to create a .NET Core API and send a POST request. I am using the template provided by Visual Studio, but I get {"":["The input was not valid."]}. What am I missing?

Comment: No idea. You've not shown us how you're making the request or how it's being handled. Try giving us some code for client and server side. Without this we will not be able to help you.

Comment: Url: https://localhost:44321/api/values

Comment: Url: https://localhost:44321/api/values, method:POST, payload:{"field":"value"}, code snippet on the API side:         // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public string Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
            return "OK";
        }, This is c# code

Comment: Looks like you didn't send a body containing the value string

Comment: I am actually, this is sent in the body {"field":"value"}